# Apache Geode can't run with basic instructions

Tags: geode

I tried following the basic instructions to run a node over here https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/getting_started/15_minute_quickstart_gfsh.html, but I am getting the following issue:

```
gfsh>start locator --name=locator1
Starting a Geode Locator in /home/thiago/geode/locator1...
........
Locator in /home/thiago/geode/locator1 on 192.168.50.225[10334] as locator1 is currently online.
Process ID: 28137
Uptime: 5 seconds
Geode Version: 1.14.0
Java Version: 16.0.2
Log File: /home/thiago/geode/locator1/locator1.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: /home/thiago/apache-geode-1.14.0/lib/geode-core-1.14.0.jar:/home/thiago/apache-geode-1.14.0/lib/geode-dependencies.jar

Unable to auto-connect (Security Manager may be enabled). Please use "connect --locator=192.168.50.225[10334]" to connect Gfsh to the locator.

Failed to connect; unknown cause: Exception caused JMX Manager startup to fail because: 'java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Failed to create server socket on 127.0.1.1[1099]'
```

Before starting I made sure nothing was running on port 1099, but after running the command I checked that what uses port 1099 is the spawned java process itself:

```
❯ lsof -i:1099
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    28137 thiago  206u  IPv6 262648      0t0  TCP *:rmiregistry (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the issue is because I was using java 16 which does not seems to be supported. Using java 1.8 fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing still happens with lastest geode and JDK 17. JDK 11 is the latest stable release that will still work

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

First try downgrading or switching to the stable Java version 1.8 or 11

locator need 10334 port to start and the need 1099 for cluster connection.

To check the port availability:

```
lsof -I:[port-number]
```

Then take the PID form the above result to free up the port

To free up the port:

```
sudo kill PID
```

if it doesn't work then try

```
sudo kill -2 PID
```

or

```
sudo kill -1 PID
```

or

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```